UseSerilog is being executed twice on Application Startup
I'm using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting and I am using UseSerilog  to bring Serilog as the only logger.
var hostBuilder = Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
hostBuilder.UseSerilog((hostingContext, services, loggerConfiguration) =>
{                        
    loggerConfiguration
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
});

However the action passed in gets executed twice, resulting in my log file being overwritten :(
I was expecting it to be executed only once, but for some reason I cant fathom why its run twice.
It was being run 3 times, and I found an errant BuildServiceProvider was being run... which I killed. There are no other calls to BuildServiceProvider.
Is there something else that can trigger a build?
Both are run after the call to await hostBuilder.RunConsoleAsync();

Something else you're using (a NuGet package, other code) could be building a service provider to do something with - it's impossible to find what that is just from the code snippet you've provided. You'd need to create a reproducible code sample that people could look through to find specifically what the problem is.

Ive been trawing and stepping through the code and not found it... https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools
I'll see if I can create a reproducable sample that's a little smaller

Ive isolated it to a call to  context.AddSingleton<ITelemetryLogger, TelemetryClientAdapter>(); however TelemetryClientAdapter never builds or does anything with the service provider.

My guess would be that something inside ApplicationInsights(?) is doing it somehow as a hunch from looking at this code: https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/blob/272c96d15bdc105b21213a032d3aa2cfeb1694d9/src/MigrationTools.TestExtensions/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L19
